# Editing questions to remove "thank you" etc

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

"*Any help would be much appreciated*" "*Thanks in advance*" etc. Should we remove them from questions, or just leave them? I know there are other meta post on this topic [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles) and all have the same type of sentiment, that this type of extra wordiness is not needed.
What is the blender exchange's feeling towards this, and when is editing a question just to remove it going too far?

Comment: I usually only remove them if I'm editing the post for some other reason anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is mostly done by people new to se and probably have experience with forums or irc and this being a QA site, it seems like clutter. I'd say remove these only if the post requires other *needed* edits, tags, spelling, wording etc, otherwise just leave it, it isn't adding or detracting anything from the post and it doesn't make sense to edit a post to just remove "hello" or "thank you".

Comment: I agree, remove if you add some mark-up anyway or do other changes. Once exception though: if it's an entire paragraph of *thank you*, *please answer* and *best regards*, I would remove that even if no other changes are needed.

Comment: The internet is filled with pedantic people, SE being no different. That being said, if it's not a part of the actual problem it's probably not useful. I do say that an edit is usually not worth it but if you do have to tweak the post, might as well strip it. I'm also not sure if "respect" is really applicable here since we are an open community and posts can be edited/improved by anyone as needed. In concluding, it's a trivial problem IMO and one should exercise their judgement. I don't see removing a "Thank you" in a cleanup offensive or detracting from a question.