# Must every question formulation be so formal?

Tags: discussion

Isn't there a bit of bringing your own personality into the question? 
I mean is it really that important to have cold not individual question formulations?
Revision because of grammar is okay but removing a have a good day and calling it "deleting the extra stuff" seems a bit too harsh in my eyes.

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have mentioned this when I edited.. It's not some much "formal" as just reducing clutter. A paragraph saying "I hope you can help me, have a good day, thanks :)" doesn't add any new information to the post, as it's kindof a given that the OP hopes someone can help them (given that they are posting a question).. See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/466/599

Comment: I agree with the "I hope you can help me" it's pointless.  I think "Have a good day, thanks" is really just polite behavior and it's really not something people should drop for the sake of "rules"  If that's what's being pushed then the rules are very wrong or being used in a way that was never intended.  After all we are not robots and being curt when typing messages online tends to sound bossy and rude.

Comment: @MarcClintDion It can come out that way, but I think here on SE this is pretty much accepted as the norm without seeming bossy. At least in my mind, I think a lot of the tone is conveyed by the phrasing of the useful information, without the need for extraneous phrases that take up an extra few seconds to read without really providing any information. Also these aren't really hard rules per se, more like conventions that most SE users seem to follow. Usually I don't edit out this sort of stuff unless I'm already editing for another reason, but I made an exception in this case due to the amount

Comment: @MarcClintDion I seem to have pretty much the same [philosophy as CoDEmanX](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/466/editing-questions-to-remove-thank-you-etc#comment1885_468).

Comment: I agree with that.  If there is a whole bunch of dialogue with a bit of standard courtesy it can just be easier to erase the whole paragraph than to pick through it all to clean up.  I was thinking that the standard behaviour that is expected of people at a public library seems appropriate.  Yammering on and on is discouraged but if you bump into someone it is polite to excuse yourself.  Thank someone if they help you except in this case the 'upvote' button is the thank you.

Comment: Exactly. I'm still frumious at Ray Mairlot for REPEATEDLY removing the engaging titles that I use as hooks to get views and hopefully answers. Examples in point: (Lightning Strikes! The Problem with Emitters) was turned into (Are particle emitters a good starting point for creating lightning?) and (Portal Majjicks in Blender's Render) became (How can I create a portal?) and (Cube Confusion: Creating a d8 in Blender from One Object) became (How do I create an 8 sided die from one object?) I'll admit to having changed the title on one of my own questions myself... twice...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of question on this topic, such as:
[Editing questions to remove "thank you" etc](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/editing-questions-to-remove-thank-you-etc)
[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)
[What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles)
[Editing for Brevity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37439/editing-for-brevity)
[Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)
[What is the policy on signatures and links in answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28416/what-is-the-policy-on-signatures-and-links-in-answers)

Here and else where on the Stack Exchange network, it commonly accepted to keep extraneous text out of questions and answers. It is not about formal vs informal writing, but rather concisely conveying the relevant information.
While salutations seem harmless, and they are; they also do not add value to the question, and as such are should not be there.
I read a reason something like this once.

> If it add no value to the question, but takes time for everybody who reads the question, why not edit out this extraneous text.

Answer (score 3):

let's discuss :)

The mere fact that someone uses the site to ask a question implies that they 'hope we can help'. The site is really about exchanging information, and though it may seem cold, distant and impersonal when we cut out the pleasantries, all we really want to do is stream-line the information, and make it consistent with how questions are presented across the Stack Exchange network.

If you feel the need to see a less formal side of the site join us in the chatroom RenderFarm, and you might get a better understanding of the separation between the *familiar* and the *matter of fact*