# Is putting my experience level a necessity?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently asked [a question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32994/why-does-image-texture-used-in-displace-modifier-not-give-the-correct-height) which got some confusing answers.

[image]

I have absolutely zero idea what they are talking about. "Render engine"? "Texture panel"? It is all just nonsense to me - They might as well be talking french.

From this point of view, would it be practical to put my experience level in a question? My previous opinion of "Sorry for this question I'm a newbie" was that it's just non-constructive noise - But is it actually required for people to know my experience level and to gauge their answers based on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not *necessary*, as a matter of fact you are in agreement with what is generally (but not too strictly) [considered extraneous noise](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/517/599) on SE.

If you feel like too many unexplained terms are flying about and you want more explanations, it can't really hurt to mention that you are an aspiring new user. But you are always more than welcome to ask for clarification (as you have done).