# Moving from other Industry software to Blender:

Tags: discussion

why is that I am looking for help with questions and "don't word things carefully" I get moderated? Are we not allowed to mention certain functions from other applications and how we can successfully migrate them into Blender? This doesn't feel fair at all?

Comment: Hello and welcome. For questions about this site inner workings and moderator actions you should use [meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com). Which moderation action do you feel was unfair or hostile? Your question as flagged as a duplicate of an existing question and this is standard practice for questions that already have a answer. To avoid this in the future I suggest doing some research prior to posting, most beginners get stuck on the same issues and we get frequent questions about the same problems.

Comment: Other that that the only other moderator action towards your post was removing "Please Help", [see here why](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2463). It wasn't flagged nor marked in any way, and there is nothing inflammatory or infringing rules of this site about it. SE has a more formal tone and stricter set of rules, if you need something more casual for your questions you can try https://blenderartists.org or other regular forums

Answer (score 7):

There are many questions like the [one you asked earlier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190100/window-min-max-when-switching-viewports): users of a certain software or app that are learning how to use blender.

There is no rule in this site not to mention other software, people do it all the time. Blender is used by many folks for many different applications or in concert with other software packages. Those who volunteer their time to answer questions here, help those users as well, if they can.

But keep in mind that blender users might not be familiar with the tools you mention, so be patient if you are asked for clarifications or further explanation of the functions you are searching for. Don't get upset if others don't understand what you want.

As for the editing/altering of posts, that is how the site works. You can edit other user's posts and others can edit yours to help clarify the question. The site is based on moderation by users.  Please take the tour (https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how to make better use of the site.

If you don't agree with the changes made to your post and feel that they change the meaning, or clarity of the question (or answer), or they destroy the carefully constructed metaphors, metric and figures of speech, feel free to roll the text back to a previous state.

Users and moderators are just people and, as such, are also likely to make mistakes once in a while (sometimes often).

But whatever you choose to do, don't take it personal.

Read also:
[Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)